# Not getting ThreadContext values even after setting "isThreadContextMapInheritable" to true, using Vert.x and Log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, vert.x, threadcontext, parallelstream

I am using Vertx and Log4j2.

This is the code for `Remote.java`

```
public class Remote extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("isThreadContextMapInheritable", "true");
        ThreadContext.put("1", "Company");
        ThreadContext.put("2", "Sector");
        ThreadContext.put("3", "Address");
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            arrayList.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        arrayList.parallelStream().forEach(s -> {
            System.out.println("Key " + s + " Value is " + ThreadContext.get(s) + " Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
        System.out.println("After parallelStream");
    }
}
```

This is my code for `StartVerticle.java`

```
public class StartVerticle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new Remote());
    }
}
```

My output when I run the above the code is

```
Key 2 Value is Sector Name: vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Key 1 Value is null Name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
Key 3 Value is null Name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5
After parallelStream
```

Could you please help me in getting the following output?

```
Key 2 Value is Sector Name: vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Key 1 Value is Company Name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
Key 3 Value is Address Name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5
After parallelStream
```

I also printed the thread name for reference.
Without using the Vertx, I was able to print all the contents in the `ThreadContext`, after setting `isThreadContextMapInheritable` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

`Vertx` and `Parallel Stream` both use the Fork Join Common Pool. Only the thread context values set before the initialization of common pool are available in the child threads.

---

Even without Vertx, the `ThreadContext` values set after the first parallel stream, will not be available in the child threads. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("isThreadContextMapInheritable", "true");
    IntStream.range(0, 5)
             .parallel()
             .forEach(System.out::println);
    ThreadContext.put("1", "Company");
    ThreadContext.put("2", "Sector");
    ThreadContext.put("3", "Address");

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        arrayList.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    arrayList.parallelStream()
             .forEach(s -> {
                 System.out.println("Key " + s + " Value is " + ThreadContext.get(s) + " Name: " + Thread.currentThread()
                                                                                                         .getName());
             });
}
```

This would print

```
Key 1 Value is null Name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5
Key 3 Value is null Name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Key 2 Value is Sector Name: main
```

---

In our case, common pool is initialized when `Vertx` starts. At that point, there are no thread context values are set.
So one option is to set the thread context in `main()` before starting vertx.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("isThreadContextMapInheritable", "true");
    ThreadContext.put("1", "Company");
    ThreadContext.put("2", "Sector");
    ThreadContext.put("3", "Address");
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(new Remote());
}
```

which produces the output,

```
Key 2 Value is Sector Name: vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Key 3 Value is Address Name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
Key 1 Value is Company Name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
After parallelStream
```

---

Comment: Thank you. But my application initiates values after the vertx instance is created. Is there a way to get values from ThreadContext, just from the way I am using it in my code?